# React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually

Tags: react-native

I am getting Error while running my project using `react-native run-ios`

> error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
>
> - react-native-document-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-document-picker")
> - react-native-fast-image (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-fast-image")
> - react-native-image-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-image-picker")
> - react-native-maps (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-maps")
> - react-native-navigation (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-navigation")
> - react-native-permissions (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-permissions")
> - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")

This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.

Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Found Xcode workspace "JustHelper.xcworkspace"

info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace JustHelper.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme JustHelper -destination id=BB2D702A-3FF7-4C11-863C-445B97ACFB83 -derivedDataPath build/JustHelper")

..

> .. error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening JustHelper.xcworkspace***

Comment: Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: unlink all dependencies. its not necessary anymore

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Anyone have any solutions for this. After I updated the react-native I am getting the above error

Comment: Still, I am not able to run project from webstrome. I run it through Xcode.

Comment: How the modules issue get resolve. Which RN version you are using

Comment: I am using "react-native": "^0.60.4", first I unlinked all the dependencies